# How do I combine two pig statements into one?

Tags: apache-pig

This two-stage `pig` processing works:

```
my_out = foreach (group my_in by id) {
  grouped = BagGroup(my_in.(keyword,weight),my_in.keyword);
  generate
    group as id,
    CountEach(my_in.domain) as domains,
    grouped as grouped;
};
my_out1 = foreach my_out {
  keywords = foreach grouped generate group as keyword, SUM($1.weight) as weight;
  generate id, domains, keywords;
};
```

however, when I combine them:

```
my_out = foreach (foreach (group my_in by id) {
  grouped = BagGroup(my_in.(keyword,weight),my_in.keyword);
  generate
    group as id,
    CountEach(my_in.domain) as domains,
    grouped as grouped;
  }) {
    keywords = foreach grouped generate group as keyword, SUM($1.weight) as weight;
    generate id, domains, keywords;
  };
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Encountered " <IDENTIFIER> "generate "" at line 1, column 5.
```

My questions are:

1. How do I avoid this error?
2. Does it even make sense what I am trying to do? 
   Even if I manage to accomplish this, will this save me an MR pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, Pig's ability to parse complicated nested expressions is unreliable. Another common error when the nesting gets to be too much to handle is `ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error at line XXXX, column 0.  Encountered: <EOF> after : ""`

I often try to do this to avoid having to come up with a bunch of names for aliases that have no meaning except as intermediate steps in a computation. But sometimes it's not possible, as you have found out. My guess is that nesting a nested foreach is a no-go.  But in your case, it looks like the first nested foreach is not necessary.  Try this:

```
my_out = foreach (foreach (group my_in by id)
  generate
    group as id,
    CountEach(my_in.domain) as domains,
    BagGroup(my_in.(keyword,weight),my_in.keyword) as grouped
  ) {
    keywords = foreach grouped generate group as keyword, SUM($1.weight) as weight;
    generate id, domains, keywords;
  };
```

As for your second question, **no**, this will make no difference to the eventual MR plan. This is purely a matter of Pig parsing your script; the map-reduce logic is unchanged by grouping the commands in this way.

Comment: I get `ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error at line 25, column 0.  Encountered: <EOF> after : ""` on your code

Comment: Darn. You may be out of luck then. But rest assured it won't add any map-reduce jobs to split the statements up.